# Something is wrong with singleton...unable adding a child because it is nil

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I use a singleton the first time and I don't really know how to implement it... 
Ok I need to explain some things: 
In **Hexagon.h** (which inherits from CCNode) I want to create multiple sprites (here referred to as "hexagons"). However, they are not added to the scene yet. They are being added in the **HelloWorldLayer.m** class by calling `Hexagon *nHex = [[Hexagon alloc]init];` . Is that correct ? Is it then iterating through the for loop and creating **all** hexagons or only one ?
 Well anyways, I have a singleton class which has to handle all the public game state information but retrieving is not possible yet.For instance I cannot retrieve the value of `existingHexagons`, because it returns `(null)` objects. Either I set the objects wrongly or I am falsely retrieving data from the singleton. Actually, I would even appreciate an answer for one of these questions. Please help me. If something is not clear, please add a comment and I'll try to clarify it.

What I have right now is the following:

**GameStateSingleton.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface GameStateSingleton : NSObject{
    NSMutableDictionary *existingHexagons;

}
+(GameStateSingleton*)sharedMySingleton;
-(NSMutableDictionary*)getExistingHexagons;

@property (nonatomic,retain) NSMutableDictionary *existingHexagons; 


@end
```

**GameStateSingleton.m**

```
#import "GameStateSingleton.h"

@implementation GameStateSingleton

@synthesize existingHexagons;

static GameStateSingleton* _sharedMySingleton = nil;

+(GameStateSingleton*)sharedMySingleton
{
    @synchronized([GameStateSingleton class])
    {
        if (!_sharedMySingleton)
            [[self alloc] init];

        return _sharedMySingleton;
    }

    return nil;
}

+(id)alloc
{
    @synchronized([GameStateSingleton class])
    {
        NSAssert(_sharedMySingleton == nil, @"Attempted to allocate a second instance of a singleton.");
        _sharedMySingleton = [super alloc];
        return _sharedMySingleton;
    }

    return nil;
}

-(id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil) {

    }

    return self;
}



@end
```

**Hexagon.m**

```
-(CCSprite *)init{
    if( (self=[super init])) {

        NSString *mainPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
        NSString *levelConfigPlistLocation = [mainPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"levelconfig.plist"];
        NSDictionary *levelConfig = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:levelConfigPlistLocation];
        NSString *currentLevelAsString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"level%d", 1];
        NSArray *hexPositions;
                if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad){
            hexPositions = [[levelConfig valueForKey:currentLevelAsString] valueForKey:@"hexpositionIpad"];

        }
        else{  
            hexPositions = [[levelConfig valueForKey:currentLevelAsString] valueForKey:@"hexpositionIphone"];     
        }


        NSString *whichType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"glass"]; 
        CGSize screenSize = [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize;

        if ([whichType isEqualToString:@"stone"]){        
            hexagon = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"octagonstone.png"];
        }else if([whichType isEqualToString: @"glass"]){
            hexagon = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"octagoncolored1.png"];    
        }else if([whichType isEqualToString: @"metal"]){
            hexagon = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"octagonmetal.png"];    
        }
        NSMutableDictionary *eHexagons =[[GameStateSingleton sharedMySingleton] getExistingHexagons]; 
        for (int i=0;i < [hexPositions count];i++){
        CGPoint location = CGPointFromString([hexPositions objectAtIndex:i]); 
        CGPoint nLocation= ccp(screenSize.width/2 + 68 * location.x,screenSize.height/2 + 39 * location.y);  

            NSString *aKey = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"hexagon%d",i];

            hexagon =[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"octagoncolored1.png"];

            hexagon.position = nLocation;
            [eHexagons setObject:hexagon forKey:aKey];
            [self addChild:[eHexagons valueForKey:aKey] z:3];
            [[GameStateSingleton sharedMySingleton]setExistingHexagons:eHexagons];


        }   
        NSLog(@"these are the existinghexagons %@", existingHexagons);
        //This returns a dictionary with one (null) object 
    }
    return hexagon;
}
```

**HelloWorldLayer.m** -> `-(id)init` method

```
Hexagon *nHex = [[Hexagon alloc]init];
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it returns `null` because the `existingHexagons` array has never been initialized in the first place. Go to the `init` function of your singleton and add:

```
existingHexagons = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

As for your For Loop question, I did not  get it. I recommend making one StackOverflow question per query instead of putting two in one.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer. Initiating the dictionary unfortunately did not solve the problem, even though it is essential   of course... The `for` loop's task is it to create multiple hexagons at their positions respectively. So if I call `Hexagon *nHex = [[Hexagon alloc]init];` it should iterate through the loop and create all the hexagons at their positions. It seems to me a little bit confusing as the class method has to return a single `CCprite*` object, right ? So creating multiple sprites would be impossible ?

Comment: Well, yeah, it seems that since the returning value type is a CCSprite, you may only return one instance of it... However, instead of returning a CCSprite type, you may instead return an NSArray. Such array would include your multiple CCSprites. So your For loop should populate an NSMutableArray, and then, at the end of the function, return such array.